# Show that $f$ is constant?!

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Problem: Suppose $f$ is a non-vanishing continuous function on $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$(closure of unit disk) that is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$. Prove that if $$|f(z)|=1, \mbox{whenever} \hspace{1cm}|z|=1$$ then $f$ is constant.

Hint: Extend $f$ to all of $\mathbb{C}$ by $$F(z)=\frac{1}{\overline{f\left(\frac{1}{\overline{z}}\right)}}$$ for $|z|>1.$

Solution:

This problem has a quick solution using the Maximum Modulus Principle. Doing it as the hint suggests, I'm having a little trouble seeing why is $F(z)$ holomorphic outside of $\mathbb{D}$?

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1}{\bar z}$ is antiholomorphic, so is $f(\frac{1}{\bar z})$ thus $F(z) = \frac{1}{\overline{f(\frac{1}{\bar z}})}$ is holomorphic. I believe it is something called Schwarz reflection principle. You need also to check that $F$ is holomorphic on the boundary of $D$.